# the argument type'List<EntryJob> Function(List<Entry>?, List<Job>?)' can't be assigned to 'List<EntryJob> Function(List<Entry>, List<Job>)'

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, combinelatest

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob6os.png)

error: The argument type 'List< Entry Job > Function(List?, List?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List Function(List, List)'. (argument type not assignable at lib\App\home\entries\entries_bloc.dart:33)

Comment: remove static from list declaration

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Please do not guess, the `static` keyword has nothing to do with it.

Comment: you are trying to assign a nullable value to non-nullable so thats why you are getting this error try adding an if block to first check for null value then return your desired results as you doing by adding a null check (!) and dont upload screenshot of code instead add the code in text format only.

Comment: Below is the updated code but errors are the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584142/error-while-combining-the-two-streams-coming-from-firestore-using-rxdart

Answer (score 1):

Why is your function taking two *nullable* lists? Especially when the first thing you do is slap a `!` behind, because you think you know better than your compiler?

You need to read a tutorial on null-safety, because this is not how you do it.

Remove the `?` behind the two lists in your parameters to make those lists non-nullable. Not only did you assume that anyway, but it is what is required as a signature by `combineLatest2`s third parameter.

Comment: sorry...
removed but the errors are the same

Comment: The errors cannot be the same if you removed that part. Please post your new code.

Comment: Below is the updated code but errors are the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584142/error-while-combining-the-two-streams-coming-from-firestore-using-rxdart

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
Stream<List<EntryJob>> get _allEntriesStream => Rx.combineLatest2(
database.entriesStream(),
database.jobsStream(),
_entriesJobsCombiner,
);
```